# Ionic Platform Add IOS

Tags: ios, plugins, ionic-framework

when I try to add platform ios to my current ionic project the following problem is occurred to me:

```
Installing "cordova-plugin-whitelist" for ios
Plugin doesn't support this project's cordova-ios version. cordova-ios: 3.9.1, failed version requirement: >=4.0.0-dev
Skipping 'cordova-plugin-whitelist' for ios
```

How to solve the problem above? What should I do for it?

Comment: Did you read the error? It says your version of cordova-ios is 3.9.1 but you need at least 4.0.0-dev

Comment: @StillLearnin How to update the version?

Comment: Did you try googling?

Answer (score 0):

When I was reading the Ionic docs, I saw a section about Cordova which is called "Cordova Updates". So...when you get an error, a good practice is to search at the official documentation - it might be helpful.

[Cordova Updates](http://ionicframework.com/docs/ionic-cli-faq/#cordova-updates)

```
$ sudo npm update -g cordova
```

In your case:

```
$ cordova platform update ios
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ cordova plugin rm cordova-plugin-whitelist

$ cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-whitelist@1.0.0
```